# error in below code using external tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I run the below code, it's giving me the following error:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   ORA-06512: at line 4

```
declare  
v_file varchar2(100):= 'samplefile.txt';  
begin  
execute immediate 'create table ext_tab2 (  
mprn char(10))  
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (  
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER  
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT  
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (  
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE  
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '||','||'  
    (mprn char(10)))    
    LOCATION ('||v_file||')  
    ) 
    PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED';  
end;
```

Can any one tell me where the error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include escaped quotes around the comma separator value:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '''||','||'''
```

or slightly more simply:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''
```

and also around the file name:

```
LOCATION ('''||v_file||''')
```

So put together:

```
declare
v_file varchar2(100):= 'samplefile.txt';
begin
execute immediate 'create table ext_tab2 (
mprn char(10))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY IMPORT
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '''||','||'''
(mprn char(10)))
LOCATION ('''||v_file||''')
) PARALLEL 5 REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED';
end;
/

anonymous block completed

desc ext_tab2

Name Null Type     
---- ---- -------- 
MPRN      CHAR(10)
```

When you have a dynamic statement issue it's often useful to display the generated statement (e.g. using `dbms_output`); simple mistakes like missing spaces are often much more visible, and when it's less obvious you can run the statement manually to get a more specific or helpful error - pointing to the point in the SQL that is wrong, rather than the `execute immediate`.

Comment: i need one more help .  if  i want to give filepath  in above code to generate log and bad file in a specific path .how can i do it .

Comment: @y2j - with [the badfile and logfile clauses](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1380). There's an example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN12898).

Comment: i have changed the datatype of MPRN to INTEGER in both the places in code
and now  "samplefile.txt"  contains data like abcd,efgh,ikhgjk....
 After that when i run the above code then data is getting inserted as  11234,113344,322444  .....    .can u tell me why this is happening????